# SELECT INTO multiple @variables MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wish to store the result of a `SELECT` statment into multiple variables.

I know that the result of this query will always return `6 ints` from 6 different rows.

I have tried using the following code :

```
SELECT id INTO @photo1, @photo2, @photo3, @photo4, @photo5, @photo6 
FROM album WHERE uploaded = @time AND scene_id = NEW.id;
```

`album` is a table.
`uploaded` is a field in `album`.
`scene_id` is a field in `album`.
`id` is the `PRIMARY_KEY` of `album`.

I have read that the number of variables must equal the number of fields. Which is obviously not the case in the above statement.

With this in mind, how would I overcome this problem?

This code is being used within a MySQL Trigger.

EDIT : Relevant Table schema as per request :

```
person   -- name of table   
id | approved -- id is PK

album   -- name of table
id | uploaded | scene_id  -- id is PK
```

Trigger is fired on change of `approved` from 0 to 1

Comment: You're gonna have to post which language you're using to drive this database.  If I'm clear on what you want, you can't do it in a single select.

Comment: I am building this into a MySQL Trigger. Thanks

Comment: Dare I ask why you want the data in variables? If you need to do anything with the data that was inserted/deleted later, why not select directly from the `OLD`/`NEW` tables then?

Comment: The trigger is being fired on a different table.

Comment: Still - you can have the trigger on one table, and from it insert into a different table, selecting from the `OLD` and `NEW` tables. Could you please be a bit more clear about what data you want to put where, and perhaps provide the schema of the tables?

Comment: Thi is not what you want, but you can maybe get along with SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id ) FROM album WHERE uploaded = @time AND scene_id = NEW.id;

Comment: the GROUP_CONCAT could be divided to different variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can join with the same table and ensure that each join will provide a new id, something like (eg. for two ids, but you will get the point):

```
SELECT a1.id, a2.id INTO @photo1, @photo2
FROM album a1 
inner join album a2 on a2.scene=a1.scene and a2.upload=a1.upload and a2.id>a1.id 
WHERE a1.uploaded = @time AND a1.scene_id = NEW.id;
```

See [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2907c/7) for a complete sql and test case.

Comment: Thank you. But I got the Error #1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger. ` select @photo1,@photo2,@photo3,@photo4,@photo5,@photo6 ;` is causing the Error. Any Ideas?

Comment: @Ríomhaire that is something else, you need to provide your trigger code body.

Comment: I am also getting this Error ; #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'.

Comment: @Ríomhaire That's probably because you already have a different trigger registered for that action.

Comment: Thanks got it working, once I did not use the SELECT. I used the variable as so `SET @ann_photo1 = @photo1;`. Then used @ann_photo1. Thanks again.